# PHP: Check image exists on URL

Tags: php

I am getting a image source from a URL dynamically, but sometimes the URL returns empty or the image does not exist so i created a `PHP` function to check if the image source do exist or not so i can display a default image to my users when the image is not accessible.

My concern, is my function enough to catch the data?

My current php function which works when its sure that a image do exist.

```
function get_image_by_id($ID) {

  $url = 'http://proweb/process/img/'.$ID.'.jpg'; 

  if(empty($url)){

   return 'default.jpg';

   }else{

    return $url;

  }

}
```

My index.php

```
<img src="<?php echo get_image_by_id($ID);?>" />
```

Comment: Your empty check seems redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `CURL` can also be helpful, tested it and working fine. Here we are using curl to get HTTP response code for the URL. If status code is `200` it means it exists.

```
function get_image_by_id($ID)
{
    $url = 'http://proweb/process/img/' . $ID . '.jpg';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if ($info["http_code"] != 200)
    {
        return 'default.jpg';
    }
    else
    {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php `is_file()`to determine.

```
if (is_file($url) {
//its a file 
   }
```

You can use a ternary operator(one liner)

```
    return is_file($url) ? $url : 'default.jpg';
```

Comment: It does work. Try accessing the URL from the browser and see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<?PHP 
function get_image_by_id($ID) {

  $url = 'http://proweb/process/img/'.$ID.'.jpg';
// Checks to see if the reomte server is running 
       if(file_get_contents(url) !== NULL) 
        { 
            return  $url; 
        } 
       else
        { 
             return 'default.jpg';
        } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_image_by_id($ID) {
 if(empty($url)){
$url = 'http://proweb/process/img/default.jpg; 
}else{
$url = 'http://proweb/process/'.$ID.'.jpg'; 
 }
return $url
}
```

Comment: This answer has a syntax error, no explanation, scope issues, and is poorly formatted.  It adds no value to the page. Please delete this answer.